# what is $InputFilePollInterval in rsyslog.conf? by increasing this value will it impact on level of logging?

Tags: linux, rsyslog

in rsyslog configuration file we configured like all application logs are to be write in /var/log/messages but the logs get written at very high rate, how can i decrease the level of logging at application level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.
Open the file in a text editor:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
```

change the following parameter to what you think is good for you:

```
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 3
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 40
```

restart rsyslogd

```
service rsyslog restart
```

$InputFilePollInterval equivalent to: “PollingInterval”

```
PollingInterval seconds
Default: 10

This setting specifies how often files are to be polled for new data.
The time specified is in seconds. During each polling interval, all 
files are processed in a round-robin fashion.

A short poll interval provides more rapid message forwarding, but 
requires more system resources. While it is possible, we stongly 
recommend not to set the polling interval to 0 seconds
```

.

Comment: Hi skr, thanks for your reply. if these parameters are not defined in my rsyslog.conf what will happen exactly..? is system will take any default values ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to this, and it depends on what exactly you're looking to do, but you'll likely want to look into [separating your facilities into separate output files, based on severity](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rsyslog-config/).  This can be done using [RFC5424 severity priority levels](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.1) in your configuration file.

By splitting logging into separate files by facility and/or severity, and setting the `stop` option, messages based on severity can be output to as many or few files as you like.

**Example (set in the `rsyslog.conf` file)**:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv,kern.none   /var/log/syslog
kern.*                        /var/log/kern.log
kern.debug                    stop
*.=debug;\
  auth,authpriv.none;\
  news.none;mail.none         /var/log/debug
```

**This configuration:**

- Will not output output any `kern` facility messages to `syslog` (due to `kern.none`)
- Will output all debug level logging of `kern` to `kern.log` and "stop" there
- Will output any other debug logs that are not excluded by `.none` to `debug`

How you separate things out is up to you, but I would recommend looking over the first link I included.  You also may want to look into the [different `local` facilities that can be used as separate log pipelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/what-is-the-local6-and-all-other-local-facilities-in-syslog).